# [ConnectionError: Failed to connect to IP in 15000ms]

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-modules

We are using mssql node.js package to updating the values in Database.we are update too more values at same times.Sometimes we faced the below error.Could you please provide a better solution to resolve that?

[image: Connection error]

Answer (score 1):

This error suggests that your database is taking too long to respond. Either add some retry logic ([Polly JS](https://github.com/mauricedb/polly-js) is good for that sort of thing) or have a look at why the updates to the database are taking so long (looking at the execution plan should help with that).